# Second column order by not working rails postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I have this query:

```
Profile.where(found: true).select("DISTINCT ON( profiles.id  ) profiles.*, integration_profiles.data as integration_profiles_data, integrations.provider as integration_providers").reorder("profiles.id, profiles.email ")
```

I know that ids are distinct, this is a simplistic example to show the problem, but it will not sort by the emails although it's included.

A more realistic example:

```
Profile.where(found: true).select("DISTINCT ON( profiles.email  ) profiles.*, integration_profiles.data as integration_profiles_data, integrations.provider as integration_providers").reorder("profiles.emai, profiles.age ")
```

And now it won't sort by age.

My profile model

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :integration_profiles
    has_many :integrations, through: :integration_profiles

    has_many :users, through: :integrations

    scope :linkedin_found, -> { where.not("meta_data @> 'linkedin_username=>null' ") }
    scope :facebook_found, -> { where.not("meta_data @> 'facebook_username=>null' ") }
    scope :twitter_found, -> { where.not("meta_data @> 'twitter_username=>null' ") }
    scope :search_keyword, ->(keyword) { where("meta_data -> 'bio' ILIKE ?", "%#{keyword}%") }



    ransacker :bio do |parent|    
        Arel::Nodes::InfixOperation.new('->', parent.table[:meta_data], 'bio')
    end
    ransacker :topics do |parent|
        Arel::Nodes::InfixOperation.new('->', parent.table[:meta_data], 'topics') 
    end
    ransacker :title do |parent|
        Arel::Nodes::InfixOperation.new('->', parent.table[:meta_data], 'title') 
    end
    ransacker :gender do |parent|
        Arel::Nodes::InfixOperation.new('->', parent.table[:meta_data], 'gender') 
    end
    ransacker :company do |parent|
        Arel::Nodes::InfixOperation.new('->', parent.table[:meta_data], 'company') 
    end

    ransacker :twitter_followers do |parent|
        Arel::Nodes::InfixOperation.new('->', parent.table[:meta_data], 'twitter_followers') 
    end

    ransacker :klout_score do |parent|
        Arel::Nodes::InfixOperation.new('->', parent.table[:meta_data], 'klout_score') 
    end

    ransacker :facebook_username do |parent|
        Arel::Nodes::InfixOperation.new('->', parent.table[:meta_data], 'facebook_username') 
    end
    ransacker :twitter_username do |parent|
        Arel::Nodes::InfixOperation.new('->', parent.table[:meta_data], 'twitter_username') 
    end
    ransacker :linkedin_username do |parent|
        Arel::Nodes::InfixOperation.new('->', parent.table[:meta_data], 'linkedin_username') 
    end
    ransacker :location do |parent|
        Arel::Nodes::InfixOperation.new('->', parent.table[:meta_data], 'location') 
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Profile.where(found: true).select("DISTINCT ON( profiles.email  ) profiles.*, integration_profiles.data as integration_profiles_data, integrations.provider as integration_providers").reorder("profiles.email").order("profiles.age")
```

Comment: Do you have some default_scope going on in your Profile model?

Comment: Added the model in the question

Comment: You could append `to_sql` to the end to get the sql query Rails generates, might help in debugging the problem. I don't see anything wrong in the models at a quick glance.